# Rails 4 error: Undefined method 'sort'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model `Thing` which has a method `popularity_rating`. Each Thing has_many UpVotes and DownVotes, and these are used to calculate the rating. I'm trying to list all Things on my home page in decreasing order of Rating, but I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in HomePageController#home
undefined method `sort' for #<Class:0x007f98edd7d330>
```

**Controllers/home_page_controller.rb:**

```
class HomePageController < ApplicationController
   def home
     @topten = Thing.sort { |a, b| a.popularity_rating.to_f <=> b.popularity_rating.to_f }
   end
end
```

**Models/thing.rb**

```
# ...
has_many :up_votes, as: :voteable
has_many :down_votes, as: :voteable

def popularity_rating
  100 * ( (self.up_votes.count.to_f)  / ( (self.up_votes.count.to_f) + ( self.down_votes.count.to_f ) ) )
end
```

**Models/up_votes.rb**

```
belongs_to :voteable, polymorphic: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method `sort` directly on a model, especially not as you have it there. That's how you'd deal with a Ruby array, and even then `sort_by { |t| t.rating.to_f }` is preferable.

What you want is:

```
@topten = Thing.order(rating: :desc).limit(10)
```

This presumes `rating` is a column in your database and not a method like you've described there. If you need to compute this value, do that in your model and save it to the database each time. Loading *everything*, sorting, and discarding all but ten records is extremely slow.

Comment: Wait, how can I save it to the database? It's actually 'popularity_rating', as shown in the Thing model. Somebody edited it to say 'rating' for some reason..

Comment: Usually a `before_validation` hook is a good place to populate any derived fields like this. Do your calculation there, like `self.popularity_rating = ...` though your numbers may jitter a little due to race conditions. If that's acceptable, don't worry about it.

Comment: If you really want to use sort on a model you can do: `Thing.all.sort { |a, b| a.popularity_rating.to_f <=> b.popularity_rating.to_f }`. In almost all cases the provided answer is the best solution, however, if you need a quick and dirty fix to sort on computed values `all.sort` will get you there.